# How to pass dynamic lookups from the request.GET right to filter in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Sending query like this **/?field1=value1** in the `request.GET` I have `{'field1': ['value1']}`.

So doing `.filter(**request.GET)` I send to it `(field1=['value1'])` instead of `(field1='value1')`.

How I can take strings instead of arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`.dict()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict) to convert it to a dictionary. In case a key contains multiple values, for example with `?field1=value1&field1=value2`, it will take the *last* value.

For example:

```
>>> QueryDict('field1=value1').dict()
{'field1': 'value1'}
>>> QueryDict('field1=value1&field1=value2').dict()
{'field1': 'value2'}
```

You thus can for example pass this to a function with `some_func(**request.GET.dict())`.

Comment: `.filter(**request.GET.dict())` works perfect. Thanks